# shuffle number data comparison in python

Tags: python-3.x, math

I am trying to figure out what's wrong with my code.
I am trying to make the computer shuffles the list until it matches A and B.

```
from math import floor
import random

count = 0;
a = '1 2 3'.split()
b = '3 2 1'.split()

def shuffler(x,y):
    random.shuffle(x)
    random.shuffle(y)

def compare_deck(x,y):
    if x == y:
        return False
    else:
        return True

while True:
    shuffler(a,b)
    compare_deck(a,b)
    count += 1
    continue

else:
    print('It took {} times of shuffle to be the same 
    arrangement.'.format(count))
```

Comment: Why did you even bother to call `compare_deck()` if you aren't going to use the result?

Comment: @downshift the `count += 1` should run every iteration, the problem is that this is an infinite loop since there is no way to break out of it. Joshua: How did you expect your loop to ever terminate? Also, `continue` at the end is *completely pointless*.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop is an infinite loop since you are not using the result from compare_deck. When the compare_deck returns `True`, you want to exit the loop, thus, your while becomes something like:

```
while True:
    shuffler(a,b)
    count += 1
    if compare_deck(a,b):
        break
```

I also erased the `continue` since it was redundant.